# Correct storage for large relational data-set

Tags: sql, lucene

I need to store a large set of what is, in my mind (although I'm used to SQL), relational data.  Basically consider storing a large subset of [ClueWeb](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09.php/) (4 TB).  There are documents, sentences, and extractions--as well as properties of each.  A major use case is running fulltext searches over the extractions.

Running fulltext searches over extractions is easily and effectively implemented using Lucene.  However, semantically extractions are parts of sentences, which are parts of documents.  Sentences and documents also have their own attributes, but when I store my extractions in Lucene, sentences and documents need to be properties of extractions.

Is there a good database engine that allows for fulltext search over extractions but also a relational structure so I can easily store properties of sentences and documents?  Or is there a way to store this data in Lucene that I don't understand?

Comment: It's true that you have a decision to make: Lucene doesn't model relations well, and most relational databases don't do full text search well.  If you describe the nature of the queries you are going to need to perform, or the end-user features you need to support, that would help condition the decision better.

Comment: A primary use case is searching over extractions (Lucene).  A secondary use case is browsing through the hierarchy (document <- sentence <- extraction) and looking at properties of each object (SQL).  A big problem is also scale.  I feel that scaling a lot of relational databases up to 4 TB would be difficult.  One solution would be to use both lucene and a relational database for data representation--but I still don't know what relational database that would scale.

Comment: Have you considered having a "foreign key" field in Lucene? That would let you do this hierarchy browsing.

Comment: @MikeSokolov, I'd be happy to accept your response if it were an answer.

Comment: @schmmd - ok - I made it an answer!  I'm deleting the comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index relations easily enough as field values in Lucene. What you can't do is perform queries with joins. But if you just want to drill up/down or get lists of all the extractions in a sentence or document, you can do that easily if you index the right keys. The place where you'll run into trouble is queries like: "all documents with title having the word 'foobar' where one of their sentences has the word 'bletch'. Even that can be overcome if you denormalize - ie copy - data in both places. But for a 4 TB index you might not want to do that.